# What is the best way to give variable/argument from one class to another using C#

Tags: c#, class, variables

What are the "good practices" in passing argiments/variables between classes? Better is using `get` and `set` or maybe giving that for example `class1.a = class2.b`?

Maybe exists better ways? Thanks for help.

Comment: What's `a` and `b` here? Are they properties or public members of classes?

Comment: Depends on the context. If the classes are related you might want to add that relation as a property itself, instead of copying references between properties.

Comment: You would first consider adding parameters to the class constructor so the object is properly initialized right off the bat and you can never forget that assignment.  Properties next.  A CopyFrom() method or factory method is sometimes wise.

Comment: Yep, there are [better ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+pass+variable+between+classes+site:stackoverflow.com). Oh sorry, you have to browse 300.000 other questions, because everybody prefer to ask a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know how you want to use this, so it's kind of difficult to give such gerenal advice in a short answer.

On the most basic level I'd say you can just use getter and setter like this:

```
public class Class1 {
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 {

    public int B { get; private set; }

    public Class2 {
        B = 42;
    }
}

public class SomeClass {

    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    ...

    private void SomeMethod() {
        class1.A = class2.B;
    }

    ...

}
```

I agree with st_stefanov that you wouldn't want to use public variables.

Answer (score 1):

That is architectural question and the answer can be large and it depends on the project and the specifics of the architecture that you use.

Generally for your example, exposing class's variables should be done via public/internal/protected Properties (i.e. via get; set;) and not via public variables. Using public variables is bad practice.

But even that is not a good in more advanced architecture.
E.g. Look at the SOLID principles.
Here is a good article which we use at work:

https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it